# Win2k3 SBS, WSUS update "stuck" waiting to be approved or declined

Tags: windows, wsus, windows-sbs

I have a weird issue, which I think *may* be related to a disk issue, but I haven't been able to prove this, so before I do something draconian (reinstall, which is a PITA), I'm hoping someone here can help.

I have win2k3sbs installed from a leftover license my employer has of an Action Pack subscription, and it was given to me so I can familiarize myself more with windows (I'm a BSD guy at a BSD-friendly ISP).  It's been working fine, and I installed the R2 on it, but there's this particular update that is just "stuck" in the Waiting for Review section.  I haven't been able to approve, or decline the update.  It hangs there until eventually the Server Management console crashes.

I think it may be a disk corruption issue, especially because it seems I'm the only one for whom this is a problem, based on my (lack of) google search results.  Does anyone know of a way I can either troubleshoot this further, or better yet, wipe out this WSUS entry and start over?

This is a VirtualBox VM running on a linux Ubuntu server I have sitting around the office which is the host.  No special config except it's running software raid5.  Disk checks came back clean both from the VM (ran chkdsk /F at startup) and the host.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the WSUS cleanup wizard - that fixes many weird and wonderful problems for me.

Also, does the Application event log give you any more clues as to what's going on?

Comment: I looked in the application log, and there is only a mention of the MSS failing, and - if this helps - IE failing with it when this occurs, though I suspect this is related to IE being closely tied to the base OS.  I'll report back with findings and result of the wizard, or confirmation that all is resolved.  Thx

Comment: Again, bear in mind that I'm not a windows admin, and this is my personal "lab" i'm starting to use... I'm a unix guy! Based on my search findings, and your comments, together with what I see on ms technet, I think I have an older version of WSUS installed, which apparently is not upgradeable, which is why I never got bumped up.  This older version doesn't appear to have the cleanup wizard you've referenced.  I've found info on the technet site about uninstalling WSUS 2.0 and installing WSUS 3.0, so if that alone won't help, I'll at least be able to run the wizard you suggested.